# Range error: Invalid array length and zero not to be displayed on selection list

Tags: reactjs

I have created a dropdown box to display remaining number of tickets for selection. I also have a number input field to give the number of ticket. Consider the input field has 5 tickets, and selected 5 in the below dropdown now if I try to change the input to zero it shows error and does not display. Another problem
is selection list should not display 0 for selection.

```
import { useState } from "react";
 const Dropdown = () => {
  const [numTickets, setNumTickets] = useState(0);
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({
    adultNonVeg: 0,
    childNonVeg: 0,
    adultVeg: 0,
    childVeg: 0,
  });

  function handleChange(event, name) {
    const values = event.target.value;
    setSelectedValues({ ...selectedValues, [name]: values });
    console.log("1", values);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Number of tickets:
        <input
          type="number"
          value={numTickets}
          onChange={(event) => setNumTickets(event.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultNonVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            ),
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childNonVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            ),
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            ),
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg +
                1
            ),
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Dropdown;
```

This is the code I tried what I need is if I change the input to 0 then the error should not occur .
zero should not be available for selection. The selection field must start from 1

Comment: explain more, what do you mean by it gives error, what error ??

Comment: when I press the backspace on number input field it gives the error like invalid array length and the screen goes blank.

Answer (score 2):

your problem was when u put numTickets on `""` and you try to make addition with that value which is impossible, so what i did is to add a test if it's `""` it will be reset to 0 and problem solved

here is the solution :

```
import { useState } from "react";
const Dropdown = () => {
  const [numTickets, setNumTickets] = useState(0);
  const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = useState({
    adultNonVeg: 0,
    childNonVeg: 0,
    adultVeg: 0,
    childVeg: 0
  });

  function handleChange(event, name) {
    const values = event.target.value;
    setSelectedValues({ ...selectedValues, [name]: values });
    console.log("1", values);
  }

  function reset(event, name) {
    setNumTickets(0);
    setSelectedValues({
      adultNonVeg: 0,
      childNonVeg: 0,
      adultVeg: 0,
      childVeg: 0
    });
  }

  console.log("setNumTickets", numTickets);

  return (
    <div>
      <label>
        Number of tickets:
        <input
          type="number"
          defaultValue={numTickets}
          onChange={(event) =>
            event.target.value === ""
              ? reset()
              : setNumTickets(event.target.value)
          }
        />
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultNonVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            )
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Non-Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childNonVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childNonVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            )
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Adult Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.adultVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "adultVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childVeg +
                1
            )
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <br />
      <label>
        Child Veg:
        <select
          value={selectedValues.childVeg}
          onChange={(event) => handleChange(event, "childVeg")}
        >
          {[
            ...Array(
              numTickets -
                selectedValues.adultNonVeg -
                selectedValues.childNonVeg -
                selectedValues.adultVeg +
                1
            )
          ].map((it, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={i}>
              {i}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Dropdown;
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make this code as a challenge and was able to do it and fix it

the problem you were having
is whenever you reset the value of numTickets by that would make your paramater passed to Array() a -ve number

because you don't reset the tickets chosen from previous state and the state still preserves their old values

so you will have numTickets = 0 but the other tickets will be more than 0 creating a -ve value
even if we fixed that by making sure the total number of remaining tickets stays above 0

your tickets will be still of some value from the old state and numTickets = 0 defying the logic
so you need to reset the num of tickets along the with the tickets chosen

please check: https://playcode.io/1055067
[image]